# Do I need two nunchucks for 2 player mode in Skylanders on the Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, skylanders

I have just bought Skylanders for my son's birthday tomorrow. Just been informed he's got a friend coming around, and they are likely to want to play Skylanders in 2 player mode. I have two Wii plus controllers, but only one nunchuck. Do both players need a nunchuck, or can I get away with just one?

I'm guessing I need two, but a quick answer may save me a midnight trip to the local supermarket.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The game requires a Nunchuk for each player, you cannot play it with Wii remote alone, sorry...

Comment: Thanks for the info - I feared as much. Quick trip to the shops for me then..

Comment: BTW, I would upvote your answer, but I have't got enough reputation! If someone could just upvote my question I should be able to do it.
Still managed to accept the answer, though.